# how to format data displayed in a column

Tags: javascript

im trying to find if there is any javascript to format a string for display, so for exam "1234"- or any string over length 2- would become 12** i know there is a replace method but not sure how this would work. any suggestions welcome. thanks much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to mask the equivalent number of characters you can replicate ***** `length - 2` times & append the 1st 2 characters of the original string;

```
var str = "123456";

var numCharsToKeep = 2;
if (str.length > numCharsToKeep)
    str = str.substr(0, numCharsToKeep) + Array(str.length - numCharsToKeep + 1).join("*")

== "12******"
```

Comment: quick question im assuming its the array function that will cause it to replicate the "*" the required amount of times

Comment: Yes; `Array(str.length - numCharsToKeep + 1)` makes an array with [string length - 2] empty elements (we `+ 1` as arrays are 0 based) then joining the array to a string with `*` as a delimiter delimits all the empty elements with "*".